# Java 9 compiles fine in maven but not in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-9

I wanted to update my project from java 8 to java 10. Hitting the well known problems of java 9 module system. However after some fiddling, researching and back and forth I was able to compile everything in maven. I added a module-info.java to my project. See also this snippet of my pom.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
                <release>10</release>
                <optimize>true</optimize>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

However Intellij is reporting 100 errors saying

> unnamed module ready package X from both A and B

and similar. I'm using Intellij Community Edition 1018.1.5. I tested it in eclipse photon and there it compiles fine. I think that IntelliJ is putting the maven dependencies differently on the module path/classpath than how maven or eclipse puts them.

However, I'm at a loss and have no idea how to convince IntelliJ to compile my project.

Comment: It would be good to share your intelliJ version and project configurations for the same as well to figure out further... And to clear out if its java10 or java9 that you're migrating to.

Comment: little off topic: when using `release`, you can drop `source`+`target`, `debug` is already `true` by default and `optimize` is deprecated, the compiler already does a lot of optimization.

Comment: Can you copy the actual error messages? This one looks incomplete to me.

Comment: @RobertScholte: Current (or at least very recent) versions of IntelliJ do/did not pick up `release`, so `source` and `target` are/were still required.

Comment: @Nicolai that's a shame...

Comment: @nullpointer I'm using intellij 2018.1.5 Community Edition. And I'm updating from java 8 to java 10.

Comment: @Nicolai I encountered that problem to, so I put `source` and `target` back into my pom. However I cheded my prject and modules setting (F4)  in intellij and it seems correct. JDK and language level been set to 10 and also the paths seem all to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to put this in a comment, since I can't really give an answer until I have more info, but you can't add screenshots to comments. In any case, did you tweak the appropriate settings under File > Project Structure > Project as in:

[image: IntelliJ Project Structure - Project Dialog]

And also under File > Project Structure > Modules:

[image: IntelliJ Project Structure - Modules Dialog]

Comment: thanks for sharing the setting screenshots. It looks all very similar to my settings, except I'm using JDK 10 and have the language level set to 10.